# Related to session_start() start on login but not work on other page

Tags: mysql, php-5.5

I am new user for PHP.I have working on some php project.want some help regarding session in php.I have login.html page which form action perform to login.js. when login perform,the Username and password has requsted url to login.php page for check username & password in mysql db table and start session_start() and set $_SESSION to username and password. If true then relocated on home.php page. but my home.php page content html code with this php code 
    
I have start session on login.php its started.I have check it by print_r($_SESSION) but when it locate on home.php it direct locate on logout.php. 
and it shows me error that 
[client 127.0.0.1:53005] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in logout.php........

my logout page contain html code with this php code 
        
and relocate to login.html page.

Comment: So why do you want to destroy it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the session before using it.

```
  session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

On every page where you want to access session variable you need to add on top of the page  session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Check this related answer in the link below [Session Start And Destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807838/ifisset-sessionusername-causing-users-to-be-redirected-from-verify-log/55807975#55807975)

> This is just the same as what is in the link above.

All you have to do is create a session for the login. So here is the trick. Each time you move from index to home, you shoulkd check if the login session exists. If not, ask the user to login.

Check if a user is logged in

```
<?PHP
    session_start();

    if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {

        header ("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Again, we first start a PHP session. The IF Statement that comes next is quite complex. But we're testing for two things: has a user session called login been set? And is this session a blank string?

```
!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')
```

The first part is this:

```
!(isset($_SESSION['login'])
```

To check if a session is set you can use the inbuilt function isset. We're using the NOT operator before it. (The NOT operator is an exclamation mark.) So we're saying, "IF the session is NOT set". The session might be set, but may have a "1" in it. We also need to check if the session called login is a NOT blank string. If both of these things fail then we can redirect to the login.php page, as it means that the user is not logged in.

For every page in your site, if you have the above script at the top of your page, it will redirect a user if they are not logged in. That way, you can protect your pages from non-members. If they are logged in, they will be able to view the page.

Logging out
If you have a look at the code for logout.php you'll see the following:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

This is all you need to log a user out: you start a session, and then issue the session_destroy command. All you need is a link to this page from anywhere on your site. The link would be something like this as your HTML:

```
<A HREF = logout.php>Log Out</A>
```

When the user clicks this link, they will be taken to the page with the code that destroys the session.

> I hope this helps.