# if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) causing users to be redirected from verify_login_form.php back to index.php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login system on my website which takes the user from index.php to verify_login_form.php and then, if the Email/Username combination matches an account they are taken to home.php . The problem that I am having is that I have

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {


header('Location: index.php');

}
```

on home.php to avoid people from just typing websitename.com/home.php without signing in/signing up. The problem is that, the user logs in with their email and password and is then taken to home.php , So they don't have to enter their username. How could I get the username of an account with the same email and password?

Here is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

header("Location: home.php");

$_SESSION["success"] = "You are now logged in";

}


?>
<html>

<head>


</head>


<body>


<form action="verify_registration_form.php" method="post">
<br>
<input type="username" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required>
<br><br><br><br><input type="password" id="user_pass_word" name="user_pass_word" placeholder="Password" required>
 <br><br><br><br><input type="email" id="user_email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" required>
<br><br><br><br><input type="submit" class="submit_registration_form_button" id="submit_registration_form_button" name="submit_registration_form_button" value="Sign Up">

</form>

<form action="verify_login_form.php" method="post">

<input type="username" id="user_email_login" name="user_email_login" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="password" id="user_pass_word_login" name="user_pass_word_login" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="submit" class="submit_user_login_form_button" id="submit_user_login_form_button" name="submit_registration_form_button" value="Log In">

 </form>


 </body>


 </html>
```

Here is verify_login_form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {

header("Location: index.php");

}else{

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "websiteusers");

if(!$connection) {

echo "Could not connect to MYSQL database";

}else{
echo "Sucessfully connected to MYSQL database";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "websiteusers");
$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
$_POST["user_email_login"]);
$userpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
$_POST["user_pass_word_login"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE UserEmail='$useremail'";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {


$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header("Location: home.php");
}else{

echo "Email/Username combination is incorrect";

}



}



}






?>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>



</body>



 </html>
```

Here is home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {


header('Location: index.php');

}



?>
<html>

<head>


</head>


<body>

<?php

echo $_SESSION["success"];


 ?>

 <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>

 <p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>


 <br><br>

 <form action="logout.php" method="post">
 <input type="submit" id="logoutbutton" name="logoutbutton" class="logoutbutton" value="Logout">
  </form>

  <?php  endif ?>

  </body>


   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is create a session for the login. So here is the trick. Each time you move from index to home, you shoulkd check if the login session exists. If not, ask the user to login.

Check if a user is logged in

```
<?PHP
    session_start();

    if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {

        header ("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Again, we first start a PHP session. The IF Statement that comes next is quite complex. But we're testing for two things: has a user session called login been set? And is this session a blank string?

```
!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')
```

The first part is this:

```
!(isset($_SESSION['login'])
```

To check if a session is set you can use the inbuilt function isset. We're using the NOT operator before it. (The NOT operator is an exclamation mark.) So we're saying, "IF the session is NOT set". The session might be set, but may have a "1" in it. We also need to check if the session called login is a NOT blank string. If both of these things fail then we can redirect to the login.php page, as it means that the user is not logged in.

For every page in your site, if you have the above script at the top of your page, it will redirect a user if they are not logged in. That way, you can protect your pages from non-members. If they are logged in, they will be able to view the page.

Logging out
If you have a look at the code for logout.php you'll see the following:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

This is all you need to log a user out: you start a session, and then issue the session_destroy command. All you need is a link to this page from anywhere on your site. The link would be something like this as your HTML:

```
<A HREF = logout.php>Log Out</A>
```

When the user clicks this link, they will be taken to the page with the code that destroys the session.